# How to add multiple value to a Field inside Document in Apache Lucene

Tags: lucene

I have some problems for adding multiple values to a field in the same Document. I have list of bugs, each bug has a id, title and several comments with comment_name,comment_text,comment_time.
  How can I add these comments information to the Document like following code? And how can I search them later?
Thanks in advanced~

```
 if (Integer.toString(bg.getBugId()) != null) {
        bugDocument.add(new Field("bug_id",Integer.toString(bg.getBugId()), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
        bugDocument.add(new Field("title",bg.getTitle(), TextField.TYPE_STORED));

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < bg.getComments().size(); i++) {
        bugDocument.add(new Field("comment_name",bg.getComments().get(i).getName(), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
        bugDocument.add(new Field("comment_text",bg.getComments().get(i).getText(), TextField.TYPE_STORED));
        bugDocument.add(new Field("comment_time",bg.getComments().get(i).getTime(), TextField.TYPE_STORED));

    }
```